# 3 teams will win the championship

Tags: probability

If the probability that 3 teams will win the basketball championship are 1/5, 1/6, 1/10, respectively, fine the probability that one of them will win the title.

Comment: plase add more information. what have you tried, where did you fail?

Comment: I guess we can assume that the events are mutually exclusive?

Comment: If the probabilities that Team A, B, and C will win the basketball championship are 1/5, 1/6, and 1/10 respectively, what is the probability that one of them will win the title?

Answer (score 0):

This question needs to be fleshed out more: how many teams are there in the tournament, how many qualifying games are played before the championship?

Comment: im sorry, the complete question is:

If the probabilities that Team A, B, and C will win the basketball championship are 1/5, 1/6, and 1/10 respectively, what is the probability that one of them will win the title?
the choices:
a. 7/15
b. 1/300
c. 7/100
d. 1